Raspberry Pi Zero W RTSP Video Stream using OV5647 Camera Module
I am attempting to stream video from a Raspberry Pi Zero W with OV5647 Camera Module in H.264 via Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP). On the receiving end, I will be using a laptop with Ubuntu 24 to view the stream.
I am doing an experiment to mimic offloading computational tasks from a drone camera and using an edge node to preprocess and request cloud-based computer vision services. Therefore, it is necessary that I utilize RTSP to create the stream and highly preferable that the video be encoded in H.264.
Python Script on the Raspberry Pi Zero W:
import subprocess
import time

# RTSP Streaming Parameters
streamPort = 554 # Default RTSP Port

def start_rtsp_stream(): # Starts RTSP Stream using libcamera
    try:
        cmd = [ # Set stream parameters to 
            'libcamera-vid',
            '-t', '0', '-v',  # 0ms timeout, Verbose output for debugging
            '--inline',
            '--listen',
            '--o', f'rtsp://0.0.0.0:{streamPort}/stream'  # Enable access from any IP
        ]

        # Start subprocess
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        print(f"RSTP stream started on rtsp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:{streamPort}/stream")
        print("Use a player like VLC to view the stream")

        # Loop until interrupted

        while True:
            # stdoutput = process.stdout.readline() # read standard output
            output = process.stderr.readline() # Read from stderr

            # if stdoutput: # This was too volumous and I commented out to avoid the additional output
                #print(stdoutput)
            if output:
                print(output.decode())  # If error, output.
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt: # Quit on Keyboard Interrupt
        print("Stopping stream.")
        process.terminate()
        process.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_rtsp_stream()

Output
When I run the script on the Raspberry Pi, I get the following outputs
camerapi@raspberrypi:~/Scripts $ python3 /home/camerapi/Scripts/StreamCamera.py
RSTP stream started on rtsp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:554/stream
Use a player like VLC to view the stream
[16:07:06.541632480] [21589]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:325 libcamera v0.3.2+27-7330f29b

A bunch of camera details in here...

[16:07:06.979875052] [21589]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1197 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-YUV420 (1) 640x480-SGBRG10_CSI2P

[16:07:06.981470025] [21594]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:622 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 640x480-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 640x480-pGAA

A bunch more camera details here...

Camera started!

Viewfinder frame 0

#0 (0.00 fps) exp 33167.00 ag 6.38 dg 1.00

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

  what():  failed to open output file rtsp://0.0.0.0:554/stream

I also tried:
libcamera-vid -t 0 -o rtsp://0.0.0.0:554/stream
Output
camerapi@raspberrypi:~/Scripts $ libcamera-vid -t 0 -o rtsp://0.0.0.0:554/stream
[16:12:09.513768085] [21704]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:325 libcamera v0.3.2+27-7330f29b
[16:12:09.885832770] [21708]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:40 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[16:12:09.906402420] [21708]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:447 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media1
[16:12:09.907872395] [21708]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1126 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
Preview window unavailable
Mode selection for 640:480:12:P
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,640x480/0 - Score: 1000
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1296x972/0 - Score: 1287
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1920x1080/0 - Score: 1636.67
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,2592x1944/0 - Score: 1854
Stream configuration adjusted
[16:12:09.927770058] [21704]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1197 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-YUV420 (1) 640x480-SGBRG10_CSI2P
[16:12:09.930069019] [21708]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:622 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 640x480-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 640x480-pGAA
#0 (0.00 fps) exp 33167.00 ag 6.25 dg 1.00
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to open output file rtsp://0.0.0.0:554/stream
Aborted

I can get the camera to show video on the raspberry pi by calling libcamera show. However, IT seems I'm having the most trouble with creating the RTSP stream.
Anyone with enough expertise know what to try next?

Hi @ChristophRackwitz. Yes, I am using a Pi Zero W running Raspbian Bookworm(which is a Linux OS).
I intend to take the camera feed from the OV5647 camera module, encode it H.264 and send it via RTSP onto the network, where a laptop running Ubuntu 24.x LTS will receive the RTSP feed and display the video on-screen.

Is RTSP important for your application or could you use RTMP? Its pretty easy to use ffmpeg on Raspi zero W to stream the camera frames encoded in h264 to an RTMP server, and you could run an RTMP server on your laptop.  Here is an example bash command to start a stream from the camera to the server:
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 5000k -f flv rtmp://local_LAN_server_IP_address/live/streamkey

ffmpeg is also capable of converting to RTSP, but I'm not an expert on that,  so explore it a bit if required by your next step.  You can find more details here: https://manpages.org/ffmpeg

Thank you for responding. I'll give that a look. I wanted to emulate a drone network that is using RTSP but I'll look into RTMP as well. I wasn't able to get the ffmpeg working RTSP either. I'll report back when I have a chance to give it a try.
